# Intersecting polygon shapefiles - features not written (error) because value is not number or exceeds maximum length

Tags: qgis, intersect

I'm using QGIS 3.16 Hannover.
I need to intersect two huge polygon shapefiles. They contain a big number of fields, values and objects. To simplify, I have to calculate habitat loss due to various projects (first shapefile) on huge areas and these areas have detailed classes within them (second shapefile).

The second shapefile containing habitat data has been created by merging various vectors, dissolving them, fixing, converting from multipart to singlepart and vice versa, v. clean, etc. It should be working fine.

When I try to run intersect on project shapefile and habitat shapefile, hundreds of features are not written to the process (feature count to habitat shapefile is 216 642). This is very important to me, because I have to have **all** the data.

The reasons why some features are not written are:

1. *String of length 65 exceeds maximum field length (15)*
2. *Value "written word" is not a number*

I have to fix this shapefile in a way that this intersection runs smoothly and doesn't skip any data. Since there are so many features, how can I resolve these issues?

I'm trying to dissolve the habitat file, but intersect won't run due to invalid geometry.

Comment: sounds like one or other or both of your input files contain bad data.

Comment: both files are government data and I shouldn't be editing them too much

Comment: Why? What makes you think the government knows what they are doing?

Comment: The first error means that the string column in  shapefile A has a max length of 15 characters but shapefile B has a string with 65 characters. It does not fit. I would edit the schema of the shapefile A to accept longer strings. Or probably I would convert both shapefiles into GeoPackage format that is not strict about the string lengths. The "written word" case feels like an error in the data and I would fix it.

Comment: The first thing I do with government shapefile data is convert it to something else (usually file geodatabase, and eventually PostgreSQL).